# Difference between glm and optim for likelihood value on logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, optimization

I still confuse my previous question on [here1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/446175/difference-between-binary-and-count-data-of-same-data-on-logistic-regression-in) and [here2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/446778/difference-between-with-and-without-weight-option-of-the-same-data-on-logistic). About logLik of logistic regression in the case of proportion(=yes/yes+no). I try to validate it using optim() by following program. But it was not same. (I could check the same value in the case with “weight=n”). When estimating as the proportion without “weight=n”, I can’t understand how to estimate log-likelihood . Please give me some advice.

logLik() : -1.547104

optim : 2.474444

```
x<-c(2,3,5,6)
yes<-c(2,1,3,4)
no<-c(3,4,2,1)
n<-yes+no
yp<-yes/n

#-----glm
modelcp<- glm(yp~x,family=binomial)
(result<-summary(modelcp))
#            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#(Intercept)  -2.0608     3.0155  -0.683    0.494
#x             0.5152     0.7038   0.732    0.464
#    Null deviance: 0.85152  on 3  degrees of freedom
#Residual deviance: 0.25523  on 2  degrees of freedom
logLik(modelcp)
#'log Lik.' -1.547104 (df=2)

#-----optim
f1<-function(para){
eta<-para[1]+para[2]*x
p<-1/(1+exp(-eta))
-sum(log(choose(1,yp))+yp*log(p)+(1-yp)*log(1-p),na.rm=TRUE)
}
(optim1<-optim(c(1,1),fn=f1,hessian=TRUE))
#$par
#[1] -2.0608361  0.5152331
#$value
#[1] 2.474444
```

it was same, “with weight = n”

```
#-----glm
modelcp<- glm(yp~x,family=binomial,weight=n)
(result<-summary(modelcp))
logLik(modelcp)
#'log Lik.' -4.548172 (df=2)

#-----optim
f1<-function(para){
eta<-para[1]+para[2]*x
p<-1/(1+exp(-eta))
-sum(log(choose(n,yes))+yes*log(p)+(n-yes)*log(1-p),na.rm=TRUE)
}
(optim1<-optim(c(1,1),fn=f1,hessian=TRUE))
#$value
#[1] 4.548172
```

my previous question1 :[Difference between binary and count data of same data on logistic regression in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/446175/difference-between-binary-and-count-data-of-same-data-on-logistic-regression-in)

my previous question2 :[Difference between with and without “weight” option of the same data on logistic regression in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/446778/difference-between-with-and-without-weight-option-of-the-same-data-on-logistic)

Comment: Why would you not use "weight=n"?  The warning message you get when you run your `glm` model should cause some concern:  Warning message:  
In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes, you are right. I didn’t notice the Warning message, sorry. And I found it would be the similar question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078497/weighted-logistic-regression-in-r

Comment: While the estimates of the parameters are the same (because all of the sample sizes are equal), you do get the wrong standard errors with you leave off `weight=n`.  I am a little surprised that the "warning" isn't a show-stopping error message.

Comment: Hmm, yes, this question was riddle, so, I did cross validation using SAS, following answer. If you are still interested in the matter, see it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the observed counts and not the fraction in the likelihood function.

It is actually a mystery to me how you can make `choose(1,yp)` work when yp is not an integer number.

The following code will give you the same likelihood as your manual optim function

```
modelcp <- glm(cbind(yes, no) ~ x , family = binomial)
print(logLik(modelcp))
```

Giving -4.548172

The Q&A [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/496932/) explains more how you can treat the data as Bernoulli or as Binomial distributed and why this gives a different value for the likelihood (it is only a difference by a constant, the functional shape is the same).

Answer (score 0):

I checked them by SAS. If I have to say the answer to my question, only “logLik()” may be wrong but glm() is OK in R. Because SE is same all(glm, optim, SAS). But anyway, I think now "2.474444" would be answer, and I couldn't find where the value “-1.547104” comes from. I don't have confidence about this answer yet, if someone makes it, please give me some advice, thank you.

optim

```
(SE<-sqrt(abs(diag(solve(optim1$hessian)))))
#[1] 3.0157115 0.7037959
```

SAS

```
data dt00;
input x yes no n yp w;
cards;
2 2 3 5 0.4 0.2
3 1 4 5 0.2 0.2
5 3 2 5 0.6 0.2
6 4 1 5 0.8 0.2
;
run;

proc genmod data = dt00 descending;
 model yes/n = x / dist = binomial link=logit;
#weight w;
#weight n;
run;

#without weight
#Deviance            :1.2762
#Log Likelihood      :-12.3722
#Full Log Likelihood :-4.5482
#Intercept           :-2.0608(1.3486)
#x                   :0.5152(0.3147)

#with weight=w
#Deviance            :0.2552
#Log Likelihood      :-2.4744
#Full Log Likelihood :-0.9096
#Intercept           :-2.0608(3.0155)
#x                   : 0.5152(0.7038)

#with weight=n
#Deviance            :6.3808
#Log Likelihood      :-61.8611
#Full Log Likelihood :-22.7409
#Intercept           :-2.0608(0.6031)
#x                   :0.5152(0.1408)
```